# Trying to pass in an object as a parameter for an innerHTML function

Tags: javascript, function, object, innerhtml

I'm trying to fill out multiple table cell innerHTML with information based on a choice of several different objects. I currently have multiple functions, one for each choice:

```
<input onClick="firstChoice();" type="radio" id="first-choice">
<input onClick="secondChoice();" type="radio" id="second-choice">

<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td id="aCell">xx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td id="bCell">xx</td> 
</tr>

<script>
function Foo(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

first = new Foo(42, 8);
second = new Foo(100, 4);

var aCell = document.getElementById("first-choice");
var bCell = document.getElementById("second-choice");

function firstChoice() {
  aCell.innerHTML = first.a;
  bCell.innerHTML = first.b;
}

function secondChoice() {
  aCell.innerHTML = second.a;
  bCell.innerHTML = second.b;
}
</script>
```

This is currently working, but I'm sure there must be a way of using a single function and passing in an object as a parameter instead of having a function for each object but I'm pretty inexperienced with javascript and can't seem to find an answer anywhere and trial and error has taken me hours. I'm looking for something maybe along the lines of:

```
function choice(choicePicked) {
  aCell.innerHTML = choicePicked.a;
  bCell.innerHTML = choicePicked.b;
}
```

Or maybe there's a completely different way of accomplishing the task - any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you actually tried that `function choice(choicePicked) {`? 'cause that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with:

```
function choice(choicePicked) {
    aCell.innerHTML = choicePicked.a;
    bCell.innerHTML = choicePicked.b;
}
```

You'll just need to change your event handlers like this:

```
<input onClick="choice(first);" type="radio" id="first-choice">
<input onClick="choice(second);" type="radio" id="second-choice">
```

This way, you're passing the desired objects to the `choice` function.